# Get service properties or other bundles using Glassfish and CDI

Tags: java, glassfish, osgi, cdi

I use glassfish 4 OSGi console for managing bundles. So, if I want to get one bundle from another one, I use @Inject and @OSGIService annotations.
When I register service in context, I put properties with it:

```
context.registerService(
        ServiceClass.class.getName(), new ServiceClass(), props);
```

Can I get these properties with bundle somehow, when I inject it?

Can I get bundle context using CDI?

And if there are different implementations of some interface among bundles and I want to get them by properties from the code, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try @Inject BundleContext context; to inject the BundleContext.
Do @Inject @OSGIService @Filter("myprop=a") MyService service; to inject a service with certain properties.

This is from the weld docs but most off it should work also for glassfish.

See this for more details:

http://de.slideshare.net/TrevorReznik/weldosgi-injecting-easiness-in-osgi